# In html only , can i use a text value in a href button?

Tags: html

i'm trying to do a simple local website to search on my db , can i with html only a Href-button using my form text value before ?

i want to write my keyword , and use this as a var in my href

```
<form>
    <p>Enter your keyword</p>
    <input id="keyword" type="text" name="motclef" /><br /><br/>
    <input type="submit" href="localhost:8888/[+keyword+]"/>
</form>
```

can i do that or i need to use some other script ?

Comment: Can't you simply use a `method="GET"`? That will add your form fields to the URL that you provided in the `action=""`.

Comment: You're totally right , i'll try to do that with the method="get" , probably the good way to do some think like that. Sorry for my non-experience in html

Comment: when i'm using that method , i can do that but there is a problem with the new link   [?page=erp-crm&section=contacts&s=]                                                   become   [admin.php?%3Fpage%3Derp-crm%26section%3Dcontacts%26s%3D=]    because the action="" part stop at the last admin.php in my link , and i need to add the end-link in the name="" part , if i fix that i'll be good and that'll work i think @Ivar

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand your comment. The GET appends the values as a querystring to the url which is defined in the `action` attribute. In PHP in your `admin.php` you can simply use `$_GET['keyword']` to get the value that was entered in the `keyword` field.

Comment: i'm using an ERP with wordpress , and i would try to do a search-engine to simplify my research with some contact , the first goal is to enter a name in the field and add this name in :localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=erp-crm&section=contacts&s=  ' myfieldkeyword ' when i click on my button to go instalty on this page , my main url don't moove i just need to change the name to search another

Comment: to do something like that :''' <form action="/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=erp-crm&section=contacts&s=" method="get" target="_blank">
   First name: <input type="text" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form> '''

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/50djebw9/1/)?

Comment: that's it ! oh thanks a lot @Ivar !

Comment: Glad it worked. I did forget to remove the rest of the query string. You don't need anything after the `?` in your `action`. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/hz3sypqm/1/

Comment: ho yes it's better, now I understand how it works really , yes that work without anything after the ''' ? '''      thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for the disturbance with my weak experience in html aha

Answer (score -2):

You cant do that with HTML, you will have to use scripts to do so.
Hint: Reload same page to get value of keyword (from input)